# how to limit the output row count of my users in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with some tables on production environment.

We have a some person that  will be access all columns and rows but I wants to set one restriction that user cant `SELECT` all data suddenly.

we have some critical information like phone number and I try to prevent publication these data.

I cant use Data Mask in SQL server for these user because they should be see all columns data.

I should be set a restriction for these user. they can get for example 100 record per select  without any row level security and data masking or special restriction.

I see the `ROWCOUNT`  but I cant set this automatic for user sessions.

these users connect with SQL Server Management Studio and all of them have data reader roll

is there any way to set this restriction on SQL server??

Comment: So these users have appropriate security privileges to access all columns in the tables, but not to see all rows in one go?  How does that work?

Comment: Even if you did somehow add a number of rows restriction, what is stopping them just running multiple versions of the same query to get the whole table?

Comment: You can add a SET ROWCOUNT = n as a parameter of the user session. I think you can do that in a LOGON trigger (to be tested)

Comment: @iamdave  no they can see all records. I wants to control these user for don't send `SELECT * FROM TABLE`

Comment: @iamdave or show 100 record per `select ` query  yes they can whole table but  It takes a lot of time

Comment: You need to change your whole setup. Don't give a user direct access to DB, make them go through an application/web server